# Windows Media Player Windows 10 "Network is too busy to play file at original quality"

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player

So up until a day ago Windows Media Player played back my video captures using Nvidia Shadowplay without any issue. These recordings had two audio tracks. One was system or game sound and the other was mic. For some reason today media player started acting up by playing the video but no system sound. A small wave looking icon in the bottom left was displayed and hovering over it I get the following message "Network is too busy to play file at original quality".  The file is local on SSD so it is not a network issue. I can go to Audio in the video and the MIC track is selected. I can manually select the system sound at which time mic sound goes away but system sound works and the wave icon goes away.

The only thing that changed was done so to get the voice feature in a game working. My system has front and rear mic inputs. I only use the rear panel. The software for the sound card gives you the option to link the front and rear mic inputs or separate them. It is linked by default. To get the voice feature working in the game, I had to set them as independent.

To my knowledge this is the only change. There were no system updates. I do know that all the recordings that I made after making that change will not play correctly in Media Player. All the ones prior do play correctly. So I am almost 100% sure that change caused the issue but I do not know why nor how to fix it.

Comment: Want to add that I can open the recorded video file in Movie Studio 13 and the video and two audio tracks show up as they always have and playback together.  I also downloaded VLC and the same issue of only one track playing but in the case of VLC the System Sound plays and the mic does not where with WMP the mic is playing by default but the System Sound is not.

Comment: Also add that I downloaded OBS Studio, which is another recording app. Same issue with files output there. WMP only plays one track, same with VLC.

Comment: Also just did a system restore to a point prior to my change, when everything was working, but the problem still persists.

Comment: ....and as a last resort I formatted and did a fresh Window 10 install. This did not fix the problem so I can only assume that somewhere along the way and update took place, either windows, video card or sound card of which I was not aware.